# divide 4 digit of integer into 2 in one variable as a tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

split(aTime), which accepts a parameter representing a time in 24-hour mode. The function will return the time as a tuple consists of two integers – the hour and minute of the parametric time.

from :
split(1240)

so aTime have 2 integer aTime(12,40)

like how we divide the 3/4 digit into two, so if the input 725 it will be 7,25 or 1234 it will be 12,34

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: The python divmod will give the result you need: divmod(240,100) -> (2,40).
I think you should omit the leading 0 in you number, because that can cause the interpreter to use octal encoding.

Comment: `0240` is invalid syntax. Do you have an integer like `240` or a string like `'0240'`?

Comment: like how we divide the 3/4 digit into two, so if the input 725 it will be 7,25 or 1234 it will be 12,34

Answer (score 1):

If your time is given as an integer, then you can use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod).

```
def time_split(time):
    return divmod(time, 100)

my_time = time_split(1240)

print(my_time) # (12, 40)
```

If your time is given as a string, then you can use slicing.

```
def time_split(time):
    return int(time[:-2]), int(time[-2:])
```

Comment: how we keep the (12,40) in one variable?

Comment: @IvandyNezha It is. in the above example it has been stored in `my_time`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unclear if the input is a string or an integer I took a generic approach.

```
def time_split(value):
    normalized_value = f'{value:0>4}'
    return int(normalized_value[:2]), int(normalized_value[2:])
```

Alternative version:

```
def time_split(value):
    return divmod(int(value), 100)
```

Comment: sorry, the input is integer

Comment: This works with both. You might want to update the answer from Olivier Melançon, because he came up with the `divmod` idea first.

Answer (score 1):

In basic shool you probably learned division like this: 13 divided by 5 is 2 with 3 remaining.

We have this concept in computer programming as well, but it is usually split in two operations:

- Part 1: Integer division: `13 // 5 = 2` (gives you the result)
- Part 2: modulo: `13 % 5 = 3` (gives you the remainder)

For your problem, you can use 100 for that division operation. 725 divided by 100 is 7 with 25 remaining (7 hours 25 minutes). 1234 divided by 100 is 12 with 34 remaining (12 hours and 34 minutes).

```
def time_split(number:int) -> tuple:
    hours = number // 100    
    minutes = number % 100
    return (hours, minutes)   # A tuple holding both numbers
```

Comment: Nice explanation.